# Parse Web Service Object

Tags: php, web-services, oop

I have a PHP webservice that returns the following

```
$response = $client->submit($requestParams);

stdClass Object
(
    [return] => stdClass Object
        (
            [result_code] => 0
            [result_data] => City=Chicago
            [message_text] => 
        )

)
```

What I want is not to assign `[result_data] => City=Chicago` to a variable like

`$city = [result_data] => City=Chicago` so that

`$city = Chicago;`

So be clear if I do a print_r($response) I get

```
stdClass Object
(
    [return] => stdClass Object
        (
            [result_code] => 0
            [result_data] => City=Chicago
            [message_text] => 
        )

)
```

from this I only want the value for [result_data] in this example that value would be the string "City=Chicago"

Comment: The output maybe is in a bad format, maybe would be: `[result_data] => City => Chicago`. Maybe City is a property inside `result_data` or maybe i am wrong and `City=Chicago` is a string

Comment: City=Chicago is a string that is returned from the webservice if this was an array it would look something like return[result_data] = "City=Chicago" if this was the case then I would strip out the City= portion and assign Chicago to $city

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it -

```
$arrRD = explode('=',$response->return->result_data); // separates the City=Chicago string into an array
$city = $arrRD[1]; // 'Chicago' is the second part of the array
```

EDIT: PhpFiddle - http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/8ut6-mtg3

Answer (score 1):

If `City=Chicago` is a string you can do this:

```
$response = new stdClass(); // this is a sample object taking your example

$response->result_code = 0;
$response->result_data = 'City=Chicago';
$response->message_text = '';

$result = explode('=', $response->result_data);

${$result[0]} = $result[1]; // or $City = $result[1];
echo $City;
```

Hope this works for you :)